# GreenRobot EventBus- start a new Fragment using EventBus

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

GreenRobot EventBus- start a new Fragment using EventBus
I am posting a new Fragment using EventBus Library but nothing happens.

I am using this method

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new CallScreenEvent(<Class>,arg));
```

I have taken a sample code from github, in which this library is using
When I take "A" class already used in project, then above mentioned method works fine but when I am using "B" class which I am integrating in the project, then nothing happens.
Am I missing any thing, I mean is it necessary to register class or something else.

Comment: Please avoid asking your friends to upvote "questions" without real content. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I am stucking at use of this Library. If you can help me, Please. Its really thankful to you

Comment: Can you paste some code where you are posting fragment using event bus and are you registering to the event bus..